# How do I add rows from a table of a MySQL database A to an existing table in database B

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL. 
I have a "customers" table in database A (located on server).

I want to add them to the customer table in database B (located on localhost) without deleting anything.

I'm very new to SQL commands or MySQL in general so try to be the most explanatory as you can. 
If you need more information  about something I will edit the post and add it.

(I have MySQL workbench)

Thanks.

Comment: do you just want to migrate from server to client ..

Comment: ^ yes. from server to localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On server (DB A)**:

```
# Sets our database as default, so we wont have to write `database`.`table` in the consecutive queries.
# Replace *database* with your database name. 
USE *database*;

# Makes a copy of the customers table - named customers_export.
# This copy contains all the fields and rows from the original table (without indexes),
# and if you want, you can add a WHERE clause to filter out some data
CREATE TABLE `customers_export` SELECT * FROM `customers`;
```

Since you are using mysql_workbench, Do a Data Export (in MANAGEMENT section) by choosing the relevant database and *only* the customers_export table.

**On localhost (DB B)**:

Assuming the database name is the same (otherwise you will need to change the database name in the dump file), do a Data Import/Restore by selecting the dump file which we exported in the previous step. 
This will create the customer_export table.

```
# Set as default
USE *database*;

# If the data you want to import contains *NO* collisions (same primary or unique values in both tables), the structure and table name is the same
INSERT INTO `customers` SELECT * FROM `customers_export`;
```

And we are done.
If it does have collisions, or you want to play change the column names, some values and etc - you will need to either modify the select statement or update the customers_export table to suit your needs.

Also, back up the customers table on the second server - in case something goes wrong with the insert.

Finally - drop the customers_export table on both servers.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this on localhost:

```
mysqldump -u YOUR_DATABASE_USER -p YOUR_DATABASE_PASS -h YOUR_SERVER_IP databaseA customers > customer.sql
mysql -u YOUR_DATABASE_USER -p YOUR_DATABASE_PASS databaseB < customer.sql
```

PD: If want some explanation just tell me

Comment: do I run both of them ? 
or one after an other? 
Does it make a difference if I have an ID with defined as index and AI  ?

Comment: You need to run both of them, first `mysqldump` to dump all data to one sql file and then `mysql` to insert in your local table

Comment: "Does it make a difference if I have an ID with defined as index and AI" don't understand what are you asking :(, please explain

Comment: I have an id row, that has auto increment. if there are the same ids from in both tables, will it make any problems?

Comment: All the data in your table (localhost) will disappear

Comment: So no, As I asked, I want to add rows to my database from the table on the server.

Comment: Oh, ok, then i think it cannot be done only using Mysql commands... you'll need to make some kind of script